# Is it possible to provide read only access via Kibana console

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to provide read only access via Kibana console, I want to create a read only kibana user which allows the console to do only read only access. Is it possible?

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html#set-built-in-user-passwords
```

Comment: what do you mean by Kibana console exactly?

Comment: the queries which we can run from the kibana endpoint against the elasticsearch instance

Comment: ok just wanted to check. you can enable audit logging to capture this - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enable-audit-logging.html